# Hide submit button using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

How do I hide the submit button using javascript? Reason is because my form checkboxes submits the form on click but only when JS is enabled. For those with JS disabled, I want them to see the submit button, so I want to hide the submit button using JS. I'm using Codeigniter if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Then use script to hide the button with `submitButtonRef.style.visibility = 'hidden';`, after the button is in the DOM of course (use the load event or similar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why javascript when [noscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript) will do the job:

```
<form>
.
.
.
<noscript>
<input type="submit" />
</noscript>
</form>
```

Comment: i want those with javascript enabled to not see the button, those without to see the button.

Comment: @Nyxynyx And that is EXACTLY what will happen with the code above. Invisible to those with JS present and enabled, visible to everyone else. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

simple javascript,

```
<body onload="hideButton()">
<script>
function hideButton()
{
    document.getElementById("buttonId").style.display='none';
    //or you can try
    //document.getElementById("buttonId").style.visibility='hidden';
}
</script>

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="buttonId" />
</body>
```

Comment: display=none Will make an element act like it is removed from the DOM, so other elements around the button will then readjust themselves to fill the void (depending on their style settings).

visibility=hidden acts like adjusting the element transparency to zero.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to hide a submit button:

```
<form method="post/get" action="#">
<input type="Text" name="xyz">
<input type="submit" style="visibility:hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Necromancer. Do you even realize this has an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#buttonId').hide(); 

});`