# How to hide a button after onclick event with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide a button after onclick event with JavaScript. My button is located at the top of the page so when someone clicks on it, content is showed but the button still on the page. I was thinking if I could hide it after the user click on the button.

Do you have any hint on how to do it?

Here is the code that I am using:

```js
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('menuDiv').style.display = "block";
 }
```

```css
#menuDiv{
        display: none; 
}​
```

```html
<div class="text-center">

        <button onclick="showDiv()" class="btn btn-light"><img src="images/cartoon-cookie.png" alt="Cookie"
                style="height:100px;">Yes, I want to see the menu</button>
    </div>

    <div id="menuDiv">
    <!-- here is the content that is revealed after the on click event -->
    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/p9bstq63/2/ is this you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide submit button using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054081/hide-submit-button-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript hide/show element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242976/javascript-hide-show-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('menuDiv').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('btn').style.display = "none";
 }
```

```css
#menuDiv{
        display: none; 
}​
```

```html
<div class="text-center">

        <button id='btn' onclick="showDiv()" class="btn btn-light"><img src="images/cartoon-cookie.png" alt="Cookie"
                style="height:100px;">Yes, I want to see the menu</button>
    </div>

    <div id="menuDiv">
    <!-- here is the content that is revealed after the on click event -->
    </div>
```

You have to use this for hiding button

```
document.getElementById('btn').style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Oh that's perfect!! thank you so much!! I didn't see that was easy to add an id an hide the button :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('menuDiv').style.display = "block";
 }
```

```css
#menuDiv{
        display: none; 
}​
```

```html
<div class="text-center">

        <button id = "myBtn" onclick="showDiv()" class="btn btn-light"><img src="images/cartoon-cookie.png" alt="Cookie"
                style="height:100px;">Yes, I want to see the menu</button>
    </div>

    <div id="menuDiv">
    <!-- here is the content that is revealed after the on click event -->
    </div>
```

In the above code, you need to add

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').style.display = "none";
```

in showDiv function below `document.getElementById('menuDiv').style.display = "block";`

It hides the button by applying `display: none` property to `myBtn` element

---

You can also use class or tag name to fetch the element(s) and apply the property

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the button using the the style property `visibility` and set it to `hidden`. Alternatively you can remove the button from the DOM, if hiding does not suffice.